# How to serialize list of list of sets to json for insert into DB column

Tags: python, json, sql-server

I have a nested list of lists (which is further a nested python set)

```
def = [
    ['and', 'exp', 'a', {'1','2','3'}], 
    ['and', 'exp', 'b', {'4'}], 
    ['and_not', 'exp', 'c', {'5','6','7'}], 
    ['and_not', 'exp', 'd', {'8','9'}]
]
```

I am trying to serialize this to json to be inserted into a SQL Server table.

There is no way to identify how deep the list can go, but it always contains sets.

Code I am using currently -

```
str_def = json.dumps(str(def)).encode('utf-8')
```

column in table is varbinary(max) datatype

```
cmd = "insert into dummy_table(def) values (str_def)"
```

I get two errors - One is sets cannot be serialized as json, other is while inserting into the table - how to handle single quotes even though I am converting the data into a binary format.

Comment: Are you using a MYSQL Database?  Also, are you escaping out the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

you could transform your sets in lists:

```
my_def = [
    ['and', 'exp', 'a', {'1','2','3'}], 
    ['and', 'exp', 'b', {'4'}], 
    ['and_not', 'exp', 'c', {'5','6','7'}], 
    ['and_not', 'exp', 'd', {'8','9'}]
]

json_ready = [[list(e) if isinstance(e, set) else e for e in l] for l in my_def]

json.dumps(json_ready).encode('utf-8')
```

output:

```
b'[["and", "exp", "a", ["2", "1", "3"]], ["and", "exp", "b", ["4"]], ["and_not", "exp", "c", ["5", "6", "7"]], ["and_not", "exp", "d", ["9", "8"]]]'
```